# How to ProxyPass to a '/path/' instead of root '/'?

Tags: apache-2.4, proxypass, ubuntu-15.10

I am using Ubuntu-15.10 wily, Apache-2.4.12

I've been trying to use ProxyPass in an SSL enabled VirtualHost like so:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Proxy *>
    Require all granted
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /myapp/ http://127.0.0.1:8090/
ProxyPassReverse /myapp/ http://127.0.0.1:8090/
```

With above configuration, I assumed that whatever is being served by the server on that port, e.g. `web` will be appended to `https://www.example.com/myapp/web`.

However, this is not what I get. In Apache logs I get:

```
... File does not exist: /var/www/html/web, referer: https://www.example.com/myapp/
```

Is this because I don't understand what `ProxyPass` is supposed to do? Or is there something wrong with my configuration that I need to correct?

**ADDENDUM** (18 Feb 2016)

I have turned on logging for `mod_proxy` and I see the following which doesn't make sense:

```
... connecting http://127.0.0.1:8090/ to 127.0.0.1:8090
... connected / to 127.0.0.1:8090
... fam 2 socket created to 127.0.0.1
... connection established with 127.0.0.1:8090 (127.0.0.1)
... connection complete to 127.0.0.1:8090 (127.0.0.1)
... http: has released connection for (127.0.0.1)
... proxy: connection shutdown
```

I am assuming that one of the addresses in the first line is the intrnal placeholder and the other is the URL being retrieved. But why in the second line the retrieved url gets connected to `/` instead of `/myapp/` as per ProxyPass?

Comment: And the third alternative is that  your reverse proxy is configured correctly but that it is `http://127.0.0.1:8090/web` that doesn't display the correct content and returns a 404...

Comment: I have tried to reach the server with the local IP, and it works fine. I know that the server is properly working since it is on the root of the `URL`, so it is the one returning the `web` part.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but it is not what I hoped for nor what I expected from my readings on `ProxyPass`. It might be a mistake on my part, or the documentation is not as clear as it should be. `ProxyPass` can not append proxied URL to a path of an invented name. So, I had to make my application load from a directory on the designated port rather than from the root of the URL as such:

```
ProxyPass /myapp http://127.0.0.1:8090/myapp
ProxyPassReverse /myapp http://127.0.0.1/myapp
```

Furthermore, A `RewriteRule` must be used as well if there are resources that need to be loaded, e.g. queries, images, scripts, etc.

The Rewrite rules would be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://0.0.0.0:8090/$1 [P,L]
```

I feel like there are many other solution that might involve other proxy modules and possibly `RewriteRule`, however, this is the one that is as simple as my knowledge in apache got.

So, the bottom-line, at least the first component of the path must be present on both ends in order for `ProxyPass` to do it's job. I can not use `ProxyPath` to load on a path I make up without further complications in proxy settings.

I hope someone finds this answer of help.